# How can I Chain load  two flexigrids one after the other

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I need the first flexigrid to make the ajax call and load its data and when its done, the second flexigrid will make the next ajax call when it is it's turn.
How can I do this?

```
//FILL THE OFFERS GRID
            jQuery("#OFFERS").flexigrid({
                url: 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=offers&task=getOffers&page=1&format=raw',
                dataType: 'json',
                singleSelect:true,          
                colModel : [
                    {display: 'id', name : 'id', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'startdate', name : 'startdate', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'enddate', name : 'enddate', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'product_name', name : 'product_name', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'discount_amount €', name : 'discount_amount', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'discount_percent %', name : 'discount_percent', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'right'}
                    ],
                searchitems : [
                    {display: 'startdate', name : 'startdate', isdefault: true},
                    {display: 'enddate', name : 'enddate'},
                    {display: 'product_name', name : 'product_name'},
                    {display: 'discount_amount', name : 'discount_amount'},
                    {display: 'discount_percent', name : 'discount_percent'}
                    ],
                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "asc",
                usepager: true,
                title: 'Offer',
                useRp: true,
                rp: 15,
                showTableToggleBtn: true,
                width: 900,
                onSubmit: addFormData,      
                height: 200,
                buttons: [
                            {name: 'Test', onpress: test}
                    ]
            });


            //FILL THE PRODUCTS GRID

            jQuery("#pnlProducts").flexigrid({
                url: 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=offers&task=getProducts&page=1&format=raw',
                dataType: 'json',
                singleSelect:true,          
                colModel : [
                    {display: 'id', name : 'id', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'name', name : 'name', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'price', name : 'price', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'}                 
                    ],
                searchitems : [
                    {display: 'id', name : 'id', isdefault: true},
                    {display: 'name', name : 'name'},
                    {display: 'price', name : 'price'}                  
                    ],
                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "asc",
                usepager: true,
                title: 'Products',
                useRp: true,
                rp: 15,
                showTableToggleBtn: true,
                width: 900,
                onSubmit: addFormData,
                height: 200,
                buttons: [{name: 'Test2', onpress: test}]
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found My answer, In order to ensure many flexigrids in my pages to work properly without making many async requests and cause the browser to mix data, I can set its property onSuccess and pass a function there.

```
//FILL THE OFFERS GRID
            jQuery("#tblOFFERS").flexigrid({
                url: 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=offers&task=getOffers&page=1&format=raw',
                dataType: 'json',
                singleSelect:true,          
                colModel : [
                    {display: 'id', name : 'id', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'startdate', name : 'startdate', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'enddate', name : 'enddate', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'product_name', name : 'product_name', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'discount_amount €', name : 'discount_amount', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                    {display: 'discount_percent %', name : 'discount_percent', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'right'}
                    ],
                searchitems : [
                    {display: 'startdate', name : 'startdate', isdefault: true},
                    {display: 'enddate', name : 'enddate'},
                    {display: 'product_name', name : 'product_name'},
                    {display: 'discount_amount', name : 'discount_amount'},
                    {display: 'discount_percent', name : 'discount_percent'}
                    ],
                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "asc",
                usepager: true,
                title: 'Offer',
                useRp: true,
                rp: 15,
                showTableToggleBtn: true,
                width: 900,
                onSubmit: addFormData,      
                height: 200,
                onSuccess : fillTheNextGrid 
                buttons: [
                            {name: 'Test', onpress: test}
                    ]
            });


            //FILL THE PRODUCTS GRID
function fillTheNextGrid(
            jQuery("#tblPRODUCTS").flexigrid({
                url: 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=offers&task=getProducts&page=1&format=raw',
                dataType: 'json',
                singleSelect:true,          
                colModel : [
                    {display: 'id', name : 'id', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'name', name : 'name', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                    {display: 'price', name : 'price', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'}                 
                    ],
                searchitems : [
                    {display: 'id', name : 'id', isdefault: true},
                    {display: 'name', name : 'name'},
                    {display: 'price', name : 'price'}                  
                    ],
                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "asc",
                usepager: true,
                title: 'Products',
                useRp: true,
                rp: 15,
                showTableToggleBtn: true,
                width: 900,
                onSubmit: addFormData,
                height: 200,
                buttons: [{name: 'Test2', onpress: test}]
            });
)
```

the source http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 0):

While I was playing around with this control I managed to do this in order to add the query later but also keep the sort, search and paging working with the same code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //AUTO FILL THE OFFERS GRID
    jQuery("#OFFERS").flexigrid({
        url: 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=offers&task=getOffers&page=1&format=raw',
        dataType: 'json',
        singleSelect: true,
        colModel: [{
            display: 'id',
            name: 'id',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'center'
        }, {
            display: 'startdate',
            name: 'startdate',
            width: 180,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'center'
        }, {
            display: 'enddate',
            name: 'enddate',
            width: 180,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left'
        }, {
            display: 'product_name',
            name: 'product_name',
            width: 120,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left'
        }, {
            display: 'discount_amount €',
            name: 'discount_amount',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left'
        }, {
            display: 'discount_percent %',
            name: 'discount_percent',
            width: 120,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'right'
        }],
        searchitems: [{
            display: 'startdate',
            name: 'startdate',
            isdefault: true
        }, {
            display: 'enddate',
            name: 'enddate'
        }, {
            display: 'product_name',
            name: 'product_name'
        }, {
            display: 'discount_amount',
            name: 'discount_amount'
        }, {
            display: 'discount_percent',
            name: 'discount_percent'
        }],
        sortname: "id",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: 'Offer',
        useRp: true,
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: 900,
        onSubmit: addFormData,
        height: 200,
        buttons: [{
            name: 'Testfunc1',
            onpress: testfunc1
        }]
    });


    //JUST CREATE THE PRODUCTS GRID 

    jQuery("#pnlProducts").flexigrid({
        dataType: 'json',
        singleSelect: true,
        colModel: [{
            display: 'id',
            name: 'id',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'center'
        }, {
            display: 'name',
            name: 'name',
            width: 180,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'center'
        }, {
            display: 'price',
            name: 'price',
            width: 180,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left'
        }],
        searchitems: [{
            display: 'id',
            name: 'id',
            isdefault: true
        }, {
            display: 'name',
            name: 'name'
        }, {
            display: 'price',
            name: 'price'
        }],
        sortname: "id",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: 'Products',
        useRp: true,
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: 900,
        onSubmit: addFormData,
        height: 200,
        buttons: [{
            name: 'Testfunc2',
            onpress: testfunc2
        }]
    });       


    jQuery("#LoadProducts").click(function () {
        //MANUALLY FILL THE PRODUCT GRID START
        //But Search,Sort,Paging wont work
        /*jQuery.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=offers&task=getProducts&page=1&rp=18&sortname=name&sortorder=asc&query=&qtype=name&format=raw",
                      dataType: 'json',
                      cache: false                
                    }).done(function(data) {        
                        //alert(data);          
                        jQuery("#tblProducts").flexAddData(data);

                });*/

        //And this will keep the sort,search,paging working
        jQuery('#tblProducts').flexOptions({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=offers&task=getProducts&page=1&rp=18&sortname=name&sortorder=asc&query=&qtype=name&format=raw'
        }).flexReload();
    });
});
```

And I add a button to execute the call to the controler

```
 <input type="button" id="LoadProducts" value="Load The product grid" >
```

But I still don't know how to chain load the flexigrids without hurting the sort,search,paging events